# My database may become unavailable for aprox. 1 second some times. How do I prevent Entity Framework connection errors?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

We have a critical application running on ASP.NET MVC 3.

Because of our failover solution, when a machine crashes, the database may take some time to recover, let's say, 1 second.

Entity Framework creates a connection everytime it saves changes or materializes objects. This connection may fail.

I'd like to implement something with Entity Framework so that it will try to connect again after a given time when the database connection fails.

I want this solution to be implemented only once per ObjectContext instance, that is, I don't want to put a try/catch surrounding every `ToList` or `First`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you still get the error, even if you specify connect Timeout attribute in the connection string for Entity Framework?

Comment: @sak, Connect Timeout will only work in case of network congestion. In my case it will just not connect and fail instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to create your own [EF Provider Wrapper](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32). This will allow you to alter logic for database connections and database commands. You will have to play little bit with EF to find where to exactly put the retry logic in the wrapper but it is IMHO the best centralized place to use without creating a whole new provider.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Transient Fault Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680906%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) by Microsoft, it's created to do exactly what you are asking.